# How to simplify this piecewise defined integral function

Tags: functions, definite-integrals

Fix $t\geq1$ and $j\in\mathbb N$. I have the following function
$$f(u)=
\begin{cases}
\int_{j-\frac{1}{2}}^{u+\frac{t}{2}} e^{x}\, dx,\quad j-\frac12(t+1)\leq u\leq j+\frac12(1-t)\\
\int_{j-\frac{1}{2}}^{j+\frac{1}{2}} e^{x}\, dx, \quad j+\frac12(1-t)\leq u\leq j+\frac12(t-1)\\
\int_{u-\frac{t}{2}}^{j+\frac{1}{2}} e^{x}\, dx, \quad j+\frac12(t-1)\leq u\leq j+\frac12(t+1)
\end{cases}$$
The first integral is zero when $j-\frac12(t+1)= u$ and it is equal to the second one when $u= j+\frac12(1-t)$; $f(u)$ is constant in the $j+\frac12(1-t)\leq u\leq j+\frac12(t-1)$. The third integral is zero when $ u= j+\frac12(t+1)$ but it is equal to the second one when $u=j+\frac12(t-1)$. I think that the writing of the function $f$ is redundant and that it can be written in a simpler form, but I don't know how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all cases, the upper endpoint is $\min\{u+\frac t2,j+\frac12\}$ and the lower endpoint is $\max\{j-\frac12,u-\frac t2\}$. And of course, the integrand is so simple that you could just evaluate the integral instead of leaving them in integral form. That being said, even though you could write it as a single expression (with max/min) instead of cases, the cases version might well be easier to work with or understand.